# 3 of the same dropdowns on one page jQuery HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think I have got myself in a twist, I would like to have 3 of the same dropdowns on one page which display clocks in different cities (so users can view more than one clock at any one time) but when I update the field for one clock it updates the other 2 dropdowns, I think this will be to do with

> $("select")

as there is nothing to differentiate between the 3 dropdowns but I cannot work it out. Can anyone help?

HTML

```
<div id="London">
  <select>
    <option value="n136">London</option>
    <option value="n240">Sydney</option>
    <option value="n179">New York City</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/n136/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th" frameborder="0" width="90" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="Sydney">
  <select>
    <option value="n240">Sydney</option>
    <option value="n136">London</option>
    <option value="n179">New York City</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/n240/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th" frameborder="0" width="90" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="NewYork">
  <select>
    <option value="n179">New York City</option>
    <option value="n136">London</option>
    <option value="n240">Sydney</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/n179/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th" frameborder="0" width="90" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('iframe').attr("src", "https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/" + value + "/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th")
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p8ARq/622/)

Comment: its not about dropdown. You are updating all 3 iframes on drop down change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not about `dropdown`. You are updating all 3 `iframes` on drop down change.

Assing `data-id` attribute to `select` and give same id to iframes and then get `iframe` id from data attribute and change its src.

html:

```
<div id="London">
  <select data-id="London-iframe">
    <option value="n136">London</option>
    <option value="n240">Sydney</option>
    <option value="n179">New York City</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe id="London-iframe" src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/n136/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th" frameborder="0" width="90" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="Sydney">
  <select data-id="Sydney-iframe">
    <option value="n240">Sydney</option>
    <option value="n136">London</option>
    <option value="n179">New York City</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe id="Sydney-iframe" src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/n240/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th" frameborder="0" width="90" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="NewYork">
  <select data-id="NewYork-iframe" >
    <option value="n179">New York City</option>
    <option value="n136">London</option>
    <option value="n240">Sydney</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe id="NewYork-iframe" src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/n179/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th" frameborder="0" width="90" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#' + $(this).data('id')).attr("src", "https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/" + value + "/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th")
  });
});
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8ARq/623/)

Comment: Why adding extra html? Just use the parent(), children() and next() functions on $(this) :P

Comment: I believe because selecting something by ID is much faster and more reliable than traversing the DOM. If the HTML ever changes this code will still work.

Comment: If you want to modify html structure in future, in that case you have to change js according to the nested parent level.

Comment: Yeah but I assumed the html structure wasn't going to be changed. Most proper html would be putting the select and iframe in 1 div so the iframe can be selected with next() ^^

Comment: @seahorsepip I would never assume structure won't change. And again, selecting something by ID is faster than traversing the DOM. And if structure does change, you don't need to make javascript changes. It just continues to work.

Comment: @seahorsepip a unique ID is always more absolute. Suggestion about `most proper html` is purely opinion

Answer (score 1):

Proper code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent('div').next('div').children('iframe').attr("src", "https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/" + value + "/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th");
  });
});
```

This is selecting the iframe relative to $(this) so you're not targeting all iframes but only the one you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make below changes in html file and in js file as below. It works as smooth. You can just copy paste and start using. It is customised as per your example. Enjoy !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="demo_script_src.js"></script>
      </head>
      <div id="London">
         <select>
            <option value="n136">London</option>
            <option value="n240">Sydney</option>
            <option value="n179">New York City</option>
         </select>
         <div>
            <iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/n136/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th" frameborder="0" width="90" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Sydney">
         <select>
            <option value="n240">Sydney</option>
            <option value="n136">London</option>
            <option value="n179">New York City</option>
         </select>
         <div>
            <iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/n240/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th" frameborder="0" width="90" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="NewYork">
         <select>
            <option value="n179">New York City</option>
            <option value="n136">London</option>
            <option value="n240">Sydney</option>
         </select>
         <div>
            <iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/n179/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th" frameborder="0" width="90" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

jQuery file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find('iframe').attr("src", "https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50r05un/" + value + "/tluk/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th");
  });
});
```